# download rate limiting based on network usage

Tags: debian, networking, ftp, router

I have a Debian Wheezy (Open Media Vault) server with a few different downloaders working most of the time. (Primarily FTP) I would like to be able to adjust the download limits of this server based on traffic from other devices.

So I have 15 Mb/s connection. When another computer on the network is using port 80, 443, or DNS, Downloads on the server get limited to 1000 KB/s. If there is a connection to netflix then its limited to 500 KB/s

Internal connections need to be unlimited all the time though. I have a tomato router that should be able to log to a syslog server. So the server may be able to watch all the network logging locally. And I think I can limit the download programs through CLI.

Can anyone suggest a good way to accomplish this? I thought I might just be able to write a simple script and run it every 60 seconds or something like that. But I don't really know where to start with that.